# Click button for a text to appear in a another form textbox

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, text

I am using Visual Studio. I have 2 forms (formA and formB). There is a button on formA. When I click it, I want a word to appear on formB. This is what I have in formA.cs.  FormB is the public class name in formB.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        FormB search1 = new FormB();
        search1.TextBox.Text = "test123";
    }
```

However, when I run my program, no text appears in formB. Can you please help?

Comment: Two questions: (1) Does your `FormB` has TextBox called `TextBox`? (2) Why are you required to make `new` `FormB` every time?

Comment: Yes FormB has a "TextBox" which is declared public. I am making new FormB to create a nwe object of FormB. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you need to create `new` object, but do not need to create it *multiple* times. In the code, it seems like you create new `FormB` object  everytime you click the `Button`. This is not always intended and I suspect your case is one of those cases.

Comment: I added the new outside my button_click method, and my program still does not seem to be working.

Comment: Then you may also want to post your `FormB` code, the initialization of the `TextBox`

Comment: You should open a public method in FormB code which set the Text value for the FormB's textbox.

Answer (score 2):

Make a constructor on FormB with parameter;

```
public FormB(string str)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  textBox1.Text = str;
}
```

then from FormA initialize FormB and pass your parameter.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
FormB search1 = new FormB("test123");
search1.Show();
}
```